If a set is strictly included in the union of a chain is it included in one of the sets
If a set S = $\cup_nS_n$ with $S_n \subset S_{n+1}$ for each n and $T \subset S$ can we say that $T \subset S_n$ for some n and why? The inclusions are strict.
I think it's true, it looks almost trivial, but i can't formally tell why.
I actually need it for groups and subgroups, but i think it won't make any difference, it looks like a set theory statement that's not influenced by the algebraic structure.

Let $S$ be an infinite dimensional vector space with basis $e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots$ and let $S_n$ be the subspace spanned by $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n$.
Showing $S = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty S_n$ is routine.
Now, consider $T$ as the subspace of $S$ spanned by $e_2, e_3, \ldots$.  Then $T \subset S$ but there is no $n$ such that $T \subset S_n$, since $e_{n+1} \in T \setminus S_n$.

+1: Nice and simple.

Consider the sets $S_n = [0, n]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$$
S = [0, + \infty)
$$
If we define $T = (0, +\infty)$, then $T \subset S$ but $T \not\subset S_n$ for any $n$.

Not necessarily. Consider $S_n:=(-\infty,n)$ for each $n$ and let $T$ be any proper subset of the real line that is unbounded above.
You can do something similar with groups as follows.
Given a subset $E$ of $\Bbb R,$ we can let $\operatorname{csf}(E)$ indicate the set of all functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with the following properties:

The support of $f$--that is, the set of domain values $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$--is a subset of $E.$ That is, for each $f\in\operatorname{csf}(E)$ $$\operatorname{supp}(f):=\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)\neq 0\}\subseteq E.$$
The support of $f$ is at most countably infinite.

Note that for any such $E,$ $\operatorname{csf}(E)$ is a group under the operation $\oplus$ given by $(f\oplus g)(x):=f(x)+g(x).$
Next, consider $G=\operatorname{csf}(\Bbb R),$ $H_n=\operatorname{csf}(S_n)$ for each $n,$ $$H:=\{f\in G:\operatorname{supp}(f)\textrm{ has an upper bound in }\Bbb R\},$$ and $$K:=\{f\in H:\operatorname{supp}(f)\textrm{ has a lower bound in }\Bbb R\},$$ Then the subgroups $H_n$ form a strictly increasing chain of proper subgroups of $H,$ $K$ is a proper subgroup of $H,$ $H=\bigcup_nH_n,$ and no $H_n$ contains $K.$

then it  doesn't work for normal sets. i still think that it works for groups and subgroups, (that's what i need it for) as removing just one element doesn't give you (generally) a subgroup. or am i wrong?

It doesn't work for groups, either. My adjusted answer (now) shows a counterexample, as do Lee Mosher's and Brian Moehring's.

Since you mention groups, here's a group theory counterexample.
Take the group $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers under addition. Let $2 = p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_n < \cdots$ be the list of all prime numbers. For each $n$ take $H_n$ to be the subgroup of all rational numbers that can be written as an integer fraction of the form $\frac{k}{m}$ such that all prime factors of the denominator $m$ are in the set $\{p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n\}$. Then
$$H_1 < H_2 < H_3 < \cdots
$$
and $\mathbb Q = \bigcup_n H_n$. Now let $T$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb Q$ consisting of all $\frac{k}{m}$ such that all prime factors of $m$ are odd. Then $T$ is strictly contained in $\mathbb Q$ but it is not contained in any one of the subgroups $H_n$.
But here is an interesting fact: if $G$ is any finitely generated group, and if $H_1 < H_2 < H_3 < \cdots$ is a chain of subgroups such that $G = \bigcup_n H_n$, then there exists $n$ such that $G=H_n$. For the proof, take $\{g_1,\ldots,g_K\}$ to be a finite generating set. For each $k=1,\ldots,K$ there exists $n_k$ such that $g_k \in H_{n_k}$. Taking $N = \max_k\{n_k\}$, it follows that $S \subset H_N$. From that it follows that $G \subset H_N$. And then, since $H_N < G < H_N$, it follows that $G=H_N$.

Perhaps I’m missing something but the OP asked for a $T$ that’s strictly contained in $S$. Your counterexample is $T=S = \mathbb Q$.

as pranay said  i meant a strict inclusion, in your example is there a proper subgroup of Q that is not included in any of the $H_i$?

Very easily fixed now.
